# File locks using ETW and Semantic Logging Application Block

Tags: c#, .net, logging, enterprise-library, etw

We have created a very simple implementation of the ETW EventSource that is consumed by the Semantic Logging Application Block (via RollingFlatFileLogs).

The basic setup is as follows:

```
[EventSource(Name = "My Applicaiton")]
public partial class MyEventSource : EventSource
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The log
    /// </summary>
    public static MyEventSource Log = new MyEventSource();
```

...

This then has the basic keywords, tasks, and opcodes.

The files are written to by events that look like:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Application starting.
    /// </summary>
    [Event(100, Level = EventLevel.Verbose, Keywords = Keywords.Application, Task = Tasks.AppStart, Opcode = Opcodes.Start, Message = "Application Starting")]
    public void ApplicationStarting()
    {
        if (this.IsEnabled(EventLevel.Verbose, Keywords.Application))
        {
            this.WriteEvent(100);
        }
    }
```

We subscribe using this method:

```
var listener = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.RollingFlatFileLog.CreateListener("C:\\ServiceRegistry\\services.log", 5120, null, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Sinks.RollFileExistsBehavior.Increment, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Sinks.RollInterval.None, null, 10, true);

        listener.EnableEvents(MyEventSource.Log, System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel.LogAlways);


        // Log some things
        MyEventSource.Log.ApplicationStarting();
```

However, the issue that we have seen is that some developers are seeing locks the log file that stops execution. A message to the tune of "the file is in use and cannot be written to" is shown.

Why is this happening? Why does it end the process even though logging is running asynchronously?

How can we prevent this from happening in the future? Is there a way to harden our logging implementation so that it can roll the file if there is an error such as this one?

Thanks!

Edit: I have captured a stack trace of the issue:

```
 The process cannot access the file 'C:\ServiceRegistry\services.log' because it is               being used by another process.

    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
     at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
    at System.IO.FileInfo.Open(FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
    at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Sinks.RollingFlatFileSink..ctor(String fileName, Int32 rollSizeKB, String timestampPattern, RollFileExistsBehavior rollFileExistsBehavior, RollInterval rollInterval, Int32 maxArchivedFiles, Boolean isAsync)
    at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.RollingFlatFileLog.CreateListener(String fileName, Int32 rollSizeKB, String timestampPattern, RollFileExistsBehavior rollFileExistsBehavior, RollInterval rollInterval, IEventTextFormatter formatter, Int32 maxArchivedFiles, Boolean isAsync)
```

Comment: Chris, it would help getting a stack trace to diagnose this.

Comment: I see this all the time, for us, it was using the same file by different applications.

Comment: @Chris can you log an issue at https://slab.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic so it can be tracked and discussed? It would be great if you could include information about the application (do multiple instances of the app run simultaneously) and also about how the listeners are disposed when the application shuts down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seeing the same problem while doing local development with IISExpress where I'm getting the "The process cannot access the file 'C:\MyPath\OurProductName.2016-01-05.log' because it is being used by another process." error message.  If I put a break point in Application_Start in the Global.asax file, I notice that it runs through Application_Start twice.  The second time is what causes the lock problem.  The only way I have found to stop this is to hunt for my own unique file name (see code below) or turn off the logging while coding in IISExpress.

Here is the routine to check for a unique file name (you will get multiple files every time you recompile or run your application in IISExpress):

```
private static string GetUniqueFileName(string directoryName)
{
   string baseFileName = string.Format("OurProductName.{0}",
      DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
   string currentFileName = Path.Combine(directoryName, 
      string.Format("{0}.log", baseFileName));
   int number = 1;
   while (System.IO.File.Exists(currentFileName))
   {
      currentFileName = Path.Combine(directoryName, 
         string.Format("{0}.{1}.log", baseFileName, number++));
    }

    return currentFileName;
}
```